# Pi3 WiFi extremely slow

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, pi-3

I know there have been several questions like this but none of them have solved my issue. I just purchased a Raspberry Pi 3 and the WiFi on it is incredibly slow. The Web application is slow and when I did a speed test in the browser it returned 80 Kbps.

I tried to just do a `wget` on a large file and it was fairly consistent at 1 Mbps, which is much better, but still not great. It's not a long way away from my router and has one wall in between the two. I really don't know what else to try to speed it up.

I'm running Raspbian Jessie and everything is up to date.

Comment: If you're fully updated on Jessie I'm not sure there's an awful lot to do aside from a thorough signal path evaluation. Eliminate everything that could possibly degrade your bandwidth: Test the router's WiFi with a known working device, evaluate the environment for interference (get away from the microwave), move the Pi closer to the router, move both router and Pi to a known good location, replace the Pi's power supply, test the Pi against other routers in other locations, disable running software, reinstall the OS, etc. etc. etc.

Answer (score 7):

make sure power management is off on Pi.

```
iwconfig
```

You should see something like this

> `Power Management:off`

If not, you can switch it to off by using

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

If you want to make this permanent you should add the following line to `/etc/rc.local` ([explanation here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=194619)):

```
iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

Comment: @loki Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/).  We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.

Comment: @Ingo thanks for the hint. What would be your preferred solution?

Comment: @loki In general you should use a systemd unit file. In this specific case there is no need to do anything. With `journalctl | grep 'power management'` you will find `raspberrypi kernel: brcmfmac: power management disabled` by default. **brcmfmac** is the wifi driver.

Comment: What are you talking about?  journalctl | grep 'power management' returns an empty string.  And as evident above, power management is certainly not disabled, otherwise it would have said it is off to start with.  Mine says it is on.

Answer (score 1):

The (very) small WiFi antenna on the Pi makes it susceptible to interference.  Other, distant SSIDs on that channel may not hear the Pi and talk over it.  Also, if there are networks that aren't on the set channel but do overlap it, the traffic there becomes simple interference and may also drown out the Pi.

Use a WiFi analyzer (there is at least one free for Android on Google Play) to see what is going on around you.  Perhaps using a different channel will help.  Channels 1, 6, and 11 are typically best due to overlap with two channels in both directions.

Seeing some overlap, I changed my access-point from channel 11 to channel 6.  My Pi3B+ ping times immediately went from 10+ms to around 1ms, and packet loss dropped from about 60% to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running new Jessie version and I get speed of at least 20 Mbits/sec which is 2 M/s in Mobile carrier speed. I've been using this as a WiFi media server for the last 3 months.

I found that the OS version and the SD card class affects WiFi speed as well as performance. Kindly share your application for further help.